# getting Custom field value in contact form 7 in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields, contact-form-7

in my website i have a page that shows the job openings. Each job opening is done it as post. So when you click on a job opening it will goes to the detail page and shows the full details.All the job detail page have a unique **job id** and it is entering using a custom field in the admin using toolset. Then all the detail page have a contact form also for send there resume.so what i need is when sending the mail i need to pass the **job id** as an hidden field and it should be shown in the mail.

what i tried is

1

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="983" title="contact 1" job ID="'.get_field( 'job-id' ).'"]' ); ?>
```

i tried this for getting the custom field value along with the shortcode....

i also tried this

2

```
    [hidden hidden-948 "wpcf-job-id"]
```

i tried this to get the custom field value in the contact form 7 itself but both the codes didn't work for me .....

is there any way to get the custom field value in contact form 7....
Thanks in advance

Comment: try this     <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="983" title="contact 1" job-id="'.get_field( 'job-id' ).'"]' ); ?> change job ID,

Comment: i checked the code you suggested but the value of the custom field is not getting ......

Comment: are you sure get_field value is "job-id" or something else check again

Comment: i am sure its "job-id"

Comment: currently i found a solution by using javascript     document.getElementById("jobid").value = "<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-job-id', true) ?>";

Comment: now its working but is there any proper solution for this using contact 7 and custom fields

Comment: ok good to know,  can you check in acf filed type is contact form 7 of job-id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use this plugin to add custom fields in contact form 7 form
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-contact-form-7-field/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I referred the link you provided ,its a good one but its last updated 4 years before ,so its not secure...